# Second derivative test

Tags: calculus

Is there a function $f$ for which the second derivative is $1$ at $c$, the first derivative is $0$ at $c$, but the second derivative is not continuous in any open interval containing $c$?

Comment: is $c$ a point or interval? Do you mean not continuous in any open cover of $c$?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the function 
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(1/x),& x\not=0\\0,& x=0 \end{cases}$$
It has derivative $g'(x)=0$ at $x=0$ and 
$$g'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$$
everywhere else. Obviously, the derivative is not continuous at $0$.

To define a function $f$ that satisfies the given requirements, add $x$ and integrate:
$$f(x)=\int_0^x (g(y)+y)dy.$$
Then $f'(0)=g(0)+0=0$ and $f''(0)=g'(0)+1=1$

Comment: To say that $g(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ you have to extend it with the value $g(0) = 0$ explicitly, as
$$
g(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll}
x^2\sin \frac 1x & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{array}\right .
$$

Comment: Hmm, and what's the difference to what I have written, except that I put this case distinction into the text, instead of one formula?

Comment: Difference is you cannot differentiate $x^2\sin \frac 1x$ at $0$, since $\sin \frac 1x$ is not defined at $0$.

Comment: Ah. Ok, I misread you're comment (I thought it was about $g'$, not about $g$ itself). You're of course right. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Kaster You may ;-) The difference quotient $(g(h)-g(0))/h=h\sin(1/h)$ is bounded by $-h$ below and $+h$ above, hence needs to converge to $0$.